# Swift button press copy text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button inside a cell inside a collection view, everything works fine except for the copy function I'm trying to create. When I click on the button the text is not copied or in my test case the text is not printed to console.

```
    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")

    }
```

In my storyboard I have a touch up inside action linked from the button to the view (I created this with ctrl-drag form the button to view). Everything looks OK but yet when I press the button nothing happens, doesn't crash either as things look OK.

What am I missing?

Comment: it is print or not  print("Button tapped")

Comment: can yiou show some additional code

Comment: `@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
    }` this is the IBAction what else would you like to see?

Comment: `cell.buttonViewLink.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Link), forState: .Normal)
        cell.buttonViewLink.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
        cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        
        func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
            print("Button tapped")` complete block, I'm using FontAwesome to draw over the button, don't think this should matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do like

**Copy**

```
 func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
       UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = yourstring!.text() // or use  sender.titleLabel.text

    }
```

**paste or Retrieve**

```
func GetCopiedText(sender: UIButton!) {

    if let myString = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string {
        print(myString)
    }

}
```

**Update**

```
 func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        print(sender.currentTitle)
         print(sender.titleLabel.text)
 }
```

**update-2**

you written the `buttonViewLinkAction` code in inside the `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` its never call. so remove the `buttonViewLinkAction` and add outside the method of data source

```
 //fontawesome link
    cell.buttonViewLink.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Link), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonViewLink.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Label text"

    }
```

**Final Answer**

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellClass
    let face = self.faces[indexPath.item]

    //set image and align center
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageURL)

    } else {
        cell.imageView.image = self.placeholderImage
    }

    //set name
    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
        cell.labelView.text = (imageNAME .uppercaseString)

    } else {
        cell.labelView.text = "oops name"
    }

    //set border
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    cell.clipsToBounds = false
    let shadowFrame: CGRect = (cell.layer.bounds)
    let shadowPath: CGPathRef = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).CGPath
    cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath

    //square background button
    cell.buttonViewSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 249/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1)
    cell.buttonViewSquare.enabled = false

    //fontawesome link
    cell.buttonViewLink.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Link), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonViewLink.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLink:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    // or use like    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)




    //fontawesome heart
    cell.buttonViewHeart.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Heart), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonViewHeart.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
    cell.buttonViewHeart.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    //fontawesome share
    cell.buttonViewShare.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Share), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonViewShare.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)




    return cell
}
```

call method like

```
  func buttonViewLink(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = sender.titleLabel.text

    }
```

or use directly already you have a function

```
  @IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
         print("Button tapped")
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = sender.titleLabel.text
  }
```

**modified Answer**

add tag in here `cell.buttonViewLink.tag = indexPath.item`

```
     cell.buttonViewLink.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Link), forState: .Normal)
    cell.buttonViewLink.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         cell.buttonViewLink.tag = indexPath.item
```

and call the methof like

```
@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
         print("Button tapped")
        let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
         if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
           print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
           }
           if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
            print(imageURL)

           }
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = sender.titleLabel.text
  }
```

Comment: That is what I was initially doing, when I noticed that was not working that is when I reverted to testing with just Print instead. Both of the examples are not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. No errors, no crash. I click on the button and nothing happens - no print or copy.

Comment: enbale the break point and check the button action is caled or not

Comment: else attach your project we will check

Comment: @user3591436 - you made the mistake

Comment: Anbu that does work, however if I take the function outside of the cell I can't get variables like imageURL and imageNAME, the 2 variables which are stored from json that I need to copy on click.

Comment: @user3591436 - method is called or not

Comment: it is, I see the print and copy works, but how can I get the variables?

Comment: I see the prints working fine, even the copy works but when I paste I get a "?" letter (for example when I paste in safari)

Comment: @user3591436 - happy to hear , can you update your question of `@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {`

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I dont understand.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, really sorry. Right now when I paste I only get a square box with a question mark inside, like this  [?]

Comment: @user3591436 - I undertand  bro, it means you copied the incorrect string

Comment: Yeah I now notice it's because of the fontawesome font type that is the reason why it's showing [?] when I paste. When I remove fontawesome I get the button label "button" during paste operation. Is there a way I can just get "imageURL" instead?

Comment: @user3591436 - ok do like , when we retrive the image URL in button action after that change your font size and copy surely works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121990/discussion-between-user3591436-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 2):

Update Swift 4.2

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(copyValuePressed)))
}

@objc func copyValuePressed() {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = label.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just posted your code. The problem is you are doing it inside function. Please take it out of it and it is working well.

Why you are not using it like this:

```
cell.buttonViewLink.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Link), forState: .Normal)
cell.buttonViewLink.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)
cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Label text"

}
```

Comment: Because that is what I was initially doing, when I noticed the copy function was not working I then reverted to Print instead as that is an easier test.

Comment: So your problem is that it is not printing even on tap?

Comment: Correct, It is not printing or copying. Neither work.

Comment: If you click on button, are they highlighted?

Comment: Yes I can see the click in and the color of the button changes when I click and then un-click.

Comment: `settings.userInteractionEnabled = true` are by default true but double check it. Add this line. And you say you connected it but why I don't see the `IBAction` before your button action?

Answer (score 1):

You have two duplicated buttonViewLinkAction functions!
When you press the button, this function will be called:

```
@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
}
```

instead of this

```
func buttonViewLinkAction(sender:UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

Remove the second function and write your code in the first function.

Also, you don't need to write this line:

```
cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

if you have already linked the button to the function (In the storyboard).

Comment: If you adding target programmatically, then no need to create `@IBAction` just `func` is fine. But if you want to connect action from storyboard to that particular button, then only you have to create  `@IBAction`.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5

```
@IBAction func copyTokenAction(_ sender: Any) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "Your String"
}
```